# What Does (%*) mean in a batch for loop?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

In the statement

```
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO Something
```

what does (%*) mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It contains all arguments to the batch file. So this loops over each argument.

Comment: Thanks Joey for Quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [Using batch parameters](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true)

> Cmd.exe provides the batch parameter expansion variables %0 through
>   %9. When you use batch parameters in a batch file, %0 is replaced by
>   the batch file name, and %1 through %9 are replaced by the
>   corresponding arguments that you type at the command line. [...] The
>   `%*` batch parameter is a wildcard reference to all the arguments, not
>   including %0, that are passed to the batch file.